# check if query exists using peewee

Tags: python, peewee

I am using the Peewee library in Python and I want to check if a query exists. I do not want to create a record if it doesn't exist, so I don't want to use get_or_create. There must be a better solution than to use try/except with get but I don't see anything. Please let me know if there is a better way. Thanks.

Comment: Is there something wrong with try/except approach?

Comment: Doesn't seem very elegant.

Answer (score 43, accepted):

You can use `.exists()`:

```
query = User.select().where(User.username == 'charlie')
if query.exists():
    # A user named "charlie" exists.
    cool()
```

http://docs.peewee-orm.com/en/latest/peewee/api.html?highlight=exists#SelectBase.exists

Comment: If I am using `db.atomic()` to "get or create" multiple related entries as part of a single transaction (i.e. **not** using the function `get_or_create()` for each entry), which in your opinion is better to use - `try/except`, or `exists()`?

Answer (score 18):

If you just need to check existence use the accepted answer.

If you are going to use the record if it exists you can make use of [Model.get_or_none()](http://docs.peewee-orm.com/en/latest/peewee/api.html?highlight=exists#Model.get_or_none) as this removes the need to use a try/catch and will not create a record if the record doesn't exist.

```py
class User(peewee.Model):
    username = peewee.CharField(unique=True)

user = User.get_or_none(username='charlie')
if user is not None:
    # found user, do something with it
    pass
```

Comment: I was surprised by the downvotes, so I clarified my answer. My reading of the question suggested they wanted to do something with the object if it existed. Which was the question I had when I came across this question.

Answer (score 3):

Alternatively, if you want to check if e.g. some other table refers this record, you can use `WHERE EXISTS (subquery)` clause. It is not supported natively by PeeWee, but it can be easily constructed:

```
subquery = Child.select(Param('1')).where(Child.parent == Parent.id)
parents_with_children = Parent.select().where(
    Clause(SQL('EXISTS'), subquery))
```

It is equivalent to the following SQL:

```
SELECT * FROM parent
WHERE EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM child
              WHERE child.parent_id = parent.id);
```

Here I used `SELECT 1` for subquery to avoid fetching unneeded information (like `child.id`). Not sure if such optimization is actually required.

**UPD** *(Feb 2022)*

After more than 5 years of `peewee` evolution, it looks like the `Clause` class is gone.

The following code may work (I didn't have a chance to test it though):

```
subquery = Child.select(Param('1')).where(Child.parent == Parent.id)
parents_with_children = Parent.select().where(
    NodeList((SQL('EXISTS'), subquery)))
```

Comment: From where do you import `Clause` ? I cannot find it in the peewee source code.

Comment: Notice this answer is more than 5 years old. Looks like `Clause` was removed or renamed since then.
You may find this useful: https://github.com/coleifer/peewee/commit/2f0b3 - it is one of the latest commits mentioning `Clause` class as obsolete and proposing a replacement.

Comment: I stumbled upon the following which seems to work: `Parent.select().where(fn.EXISTS(subquery))`. It seems that Peewee is smart enough that you don't even need the `Param('1')` in your subquery. So `subquery = Child.select().where(Child.parent == Parent.id)` actually turns into a `select 1` when used in the exists for some reason.